# Render html table from csv using node.js, express and python

Tags: python, node.js, express, ejs

I have a simple csv file and want to render a html table from it using express and ejs.

csv:

```
,Unnamed: 0,sign_type,r1,g1,b1,r2,g2,b2,r3,g3,b3,r4,g4,b4,r5,g5,b5,r6,g6,b6,r7,g7,b7,r8,g8,b8,r9,g9,b9,r10,g10,b10,r11,g11,b11,r12,g12,b12,r13,g13,b13,r14,g14,b14,r15,g15,b15,r16,g16,b16
0,1,pedestrian,155,228,251,135,188,101,156,227,245,145,211,228,166,233,245,212,254,52,212,254,11,188,229,117,170,216,120,211,254,3,212,254,19,172,235,244,172,235,244,172,228,235,177,235,244,22,52,53
1,2,pedestrian,142,217,242,166,204,44,142,217,242,147,219,242,164,228,229,84,116,17,217,254,26,155,203,128,213,253,51,217,255,21,217,255,21,158,225,237,164,227,237,182,228,143,171,228,196,164,227,237
2,3,pedestrian,57,54,50,187,201,68,51,51,45,59,62,65,156,171,50,254,255,36,211,226,70,78,73,64,220,234,59,254,255,51,253,255,44,66,68,68,69,65,59,76,84,22,82,93,17,58,60,60
3,4,pedestrian,22,35,41,171,178,26,19,27,29,19,27,29,42,37,3,217,228,19,221,235,20,181,183,73,237,234,44,251,254,2,235,243,12,19,27,29,20,29,34,64,61,4,211,222,78,19,27,29
4,5,pedestrian,169,179,170,231,254,27,97,107,99,123,147,152,221,236,117,205,225,80,235,254,60,90,110,9,216,236,66,229,255,12,235,254,60,163,168,152,124,117,91,188,205,78,125,147,20,160,183,187
```

my .html file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Table</title>
</head>

<body>
    <%= table %>
</body>

</html>
```

my app.js is:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var pyshell = new PythonShell('excel_to_html.py');
  pyshell.on('message', function (message) {

      res.render('list', {table: message}) // ###### console.log(message);
  });
  });

var port = 3000;
app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Server running on port ' + port)
});
```

and the python file which converts the .csv to html is:

```
import pandas as pd

def convert():
    csv_file = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    html = csv_file.to_html()
    return html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    var = convert()
    print(var)
```

So summarizing:

1) I have a csv file and using a .py file and pandas to convert the csv into html.

2) I'm calling the python script inside the app.js file and getting the returned html.

3) I want to render that html table in my index.html using ejs.

If I replace the `res.render('list', {table: message})` with the commented part `console.log(message);` I'm able to see the html table in the terminal log.

but when I try to render it using `res.render('list', {table: message})` i get a not infinite looping error like this:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client 
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (E:\Documents\CODE\WebDev\todolist\v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (E:\Documents\CODE\WebDev\todolist\v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at done (E:\Documents\CODE\WebDev\todolist\v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:10)
    at tryHandleCache (E:\Documents\CODE\WebDev\todolist\v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:260:5)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\Documents\CODE\WebDev\todolist\v1\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:459:10)
    at View.render (E:\Documents\CODE\WebDev\todolist\v1\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (E:\Documents\CODE\WebDev\todolist\v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (E:\Documents\CODE\WebDev\todolist\v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\Documents\CODE\WebDev\todolist\v1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
```

And I get only this in the browser:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
```

how should I render this table? Is it easily possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Express's [res.render](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) ends the response; which means we can only use it once, and it seems like the listener `pyshell.on('message'...` is being triggered more than once.

You will need to prepare the table then render it. Example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { PythonShell } = require('python-shell');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  prepareHtmlTable(function(err, html) {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(500);
    res.render('list', { table: html });
  })
});

function prepareHtmlTable(callback) {
  const pyshell = new PythonShell('excel_to_html.py');

  pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    // prepare html table here
    let html = message;

    pyshell.end(function (err,code,signal) {
      if (err) return callback(err);

      callback(null, html);
    });
  });
}

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Server running on port ' + port)
});
```

Comment: That worked! Since the listener is being triggered many times i only had to add `html = html + message;` and change the ejs placeholder to `<%- table %>` instead of `<%= table %>`. Thanks!